# Suppose $v_1,...,v_m$ is a linearly independent list, Will the list of vectors $Tv_1,...,Tv_m$ be a linearly independent list.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $v_1,...,v_m$ is a linearly independent list of vectors in $V$ and $T∈L(V,W)$ is a linear map from *V* to *W*. Will the list of vector $Tv_1,...,Tv_m$ be a linearly independent list in *W*? If it is, please give a rigorous proof; if not, give a counter-example.

I know that if we reverse the condition and results, it's easy to prove v1,...,vm is linearly independent, but I'm get stuck in this one.

Comment: What if $T$ sends everything to the zero vector?

Comment: Cool!! that's it!

Comment: The counterexample is kind of obvious when you think about it.It's why in the statements of most theorems on "independence-preserving" linear transformations $T: V\rightarrow W$ in linear algebra, we add the condition that for every $v\in V$, $T(v) \neq 0$

Comment: So if we add the condition, then it becomes true for my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No, for example let $Tv=0$ for all $v\in V$.

**Long Answer:** If null space of $T$ is $\{0\}$ you can conclude that $Tv_1, \dots, Tv_m$ are linearly independent. Otherwise, they are linearly dependent.

Comment: really appreciate it.