# On applying linearly independent definition

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation

If {$u,v$} are linearly independent in V, does {$T(u),T(v)$} have to be linearly independent in W? If so, prove it, if not, give counter example.

Can someone explains to be me clearly what linearly independent mean and how to apply it to this question??

Comment: What is the definition of linear independence?

Comment: cannot be written as linear combination of other elements I suppose?

Comment: [Similar Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1270779/287369)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the zero transformation:

$$Tv=0, \ \forall v \in V$$

It is a linear transformation (why?)

No matter what two linearly independent vectors $u$ and $v$ are, obviously $Tv$ and $Tu$ aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Let say $T=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $u=[0 \quad 1]^{\top}$ and $v=[1 \quad 0]^{\top}$. $Tu$ and $Tv$ are not linear independent.

Only, if $T$ is a one-to-one mapping, then we can say $Tu, Tv$ must be linearly independent.

Comment: Can you tell me why that is not a one to one mapping?

Comment: Take the points of the form $[1 \quad \alpha]^{\top}$ where $\alpha$ is any real number. Take away point is that rank of $T$ is $1$.